# SCNPhysicsVehicle, wheel are rotate 90 deg

Tags: scenekit, arkit, game-development, scnnode

I'm try to study Scenekit and SCNPhysicsVehicle, I created a simple car as per picture below:

[image: pic]

i wrote the following code that should load the physics to the model and place it to the scene.

```
 func setupVeicles(nodePos: SCNVector3){
        // load file usdz
        let truck = loadAssetWithName(nameFile: "car", nameNode: "car", type: "usdz", scale: SCNVector3(1, 1, 1))
        let chassie = truck.childNode(withName: "Chassie", recursively: true)!
        // add chassie at position touch
        chassie.position = SCNVector3(nodePos.x, nodePos.y+0.1, nodePos.z)

        //Set the physic body
        let body = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
        body.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: chassie)
        body.categoryBitMask = BodyType.car.rawValue //2 int, assegnato solo a quel oggetto
        body.collisionBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue  //1 con cosa puo collidere
        body.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue //1 attiva il delegato
        body.allowsResting = false
        body.mass = 5
        body.restitution = 0.1
        body.friction = 0.5
        body.rollingFriction = 0
        chassie.physicsBody = body
        
        // Load the wheel
        let wheelFL = chassie.childNode(withName: "WheelFL", recursively: true)!
        let wheelFR = chassie.childNode(withName: "WheelFR", recursively: true)!
        let wheelBL = chassie.childNode(withName: "WheelBL", recursively: true)!
        let wheelBR = chassie.childNode(withName: "WheelBR", recursively: true)!
        
       // test rotate , but not work
//        wheelFL.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(deg2rad(90), 0, 0)
       
        // wheelPhysic
        let phywheelFL = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelFL, position: SCNVector3(-0.212, -0.085, 0.146))
        let phywheelFR = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelFR, position: SCNVector3(-0.212, -0.085, -0.15))
        let phywheelBL = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelBL, position: SCNVector3(0.182, -0.085, 0.15))
        let phywheelBR = createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: wheelBR, position: SCNVector3(0.182, -0.085, -0.15))
        
        
        
        let physicsVehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassie.physicsBody!, wheels: [phywheelFL,phywheelFR,phywheelBL,phywheelBR])
        self.arView.scene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(physicsVehicle)
        self.arView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(chassie)
    }

   func createPhysicsVehicleWheel(wheelNode: SCNNode,   position: SCNVector3) -> SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel {
        
        let wheel = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelNode)
        wheel.connectionPosition = position
        wheel.axle = SCNVector3(x: -1.0, y: 0, z: 0)
        wheel.maximumSuspensionTravel = 4.0
        wheel.maximumSuspensionForce = 100
        wheel.suspensionRestLength = 0.08
        wheel.suspensionDamping = 2.0
        wheel.suspensionStiffness = 2.0
        wheel.suspensionCompression = 4.0
        wheel.radius = 0.04
        wheel.frictionSlip = 0.9
        return wheel
        
    }
```

Can't understand why my wheel are rotate 90 deg as you cans se on the picture:

[image: pic2]

Why this wheel are like this? how to rotate them.. I tried to rotate the node but nothing happen..

Answer (score 0):

Download the file `rc_car.dae` from the Scenekit Demo App that Apple provided in the past.

https://github.com/NXAristotle/appleSample/tree/master/SceneKitVehicleDemo/SceneKitVehicle/resources

You will see, that the geometry is a bit more complex, containing subnodes on the wheels. I ran into a similar issue. Then I used Blender to adapt the geometry the same way as it is in rc_car.dae to my own model. It was quite a bit of work.

Export it to DAE and use it in SceneKit.

If you need code examples, I can provide, but what you made looks quite good to me.

Comment: thanks a lot, I found out the reason looking at the Apple project.Was missing as you mention, some subside for the connection of the wheel